# FloatingActionButton hide instantly

Tags: android, xml, animation, button, layout

i have a really simple question, is there a way to hide a FloatingActionButton without the animation that comes with it? One way that i was thinking was "wrapping" it with any Layout and make it GONE or INVISIBLE. But maybe there is a simple way. Do any of you have something in mind?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: FloatingActionButton is of the type View. You can set it to GONE or INVISIBLE if you want to

Comment: I was receiving a warning from SonarLint and i thought that i shouldn do that, but it just works. I think thats it! Thanks!

Comment: You can ignore a warning or do what it tells you, but you can execute the program most times with a lot of warnings, only some throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

use visibility property to visible or gone.